# Cannot connect to apache server from local machine

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I have installed apache and php on a linux server CentOS 6.4. I followed these steps

```
yum install -y httpd
/sbin/service httpd restart
yum install -y php php-mysql
yum install -y mod_ssl openssl
/sbin/service httpd restart
service iptables stop
```

I changed the ServerName in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf from

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

to

```
ServerName 172.32.35.14 (ip address of the server)
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

I have a php sample pas with the following code:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

But when I try to access the page http://172.32.35.14/info.php from my local machine it says "Problem loading page". Whereas, I get proper response when connected to the page from 172.32.35.15

My ISP doesnt block http requests. 
172.* network is a VPN. I connected to the VPN, able to ping the machine, do a ssh connection to the machine using putty. But when I cannot access the php page from my local machine.

What am I missing? Please advice

netstat -tulpn output is:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1235/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4406/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4198/cupsd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      4636/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:52330               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1253/rpc.statd
tcp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                        LISTEN      1235/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      30170/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      4406/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:631                     :::*                        LISTEN      4198/cupsd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      4636/master
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      30170/httpd
tcp        0      0 :::46690                    :::*                        LISTEN      1253/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:1005                0.0.0.0:*                               1253/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111                 0.0.0.0:*                               1235/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631                 0.0.0.0:*                               4198/cupsd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68                  0.0.0.0:*                               1129/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:986                 0.0.0.0:*                               1235/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:39783               0.0.0.0:*                               1253/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 :::111                      :::*                                    1235/rpcbind
udp        0      0 :::38152                    :::*                                    1253/rpc.statd
udp        0      0 :::986                      :::*                                    1235/rpcbind
```

iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Is `172.32.35.15` in the same subnet or is connected to the same switch with the server ? Try changing the port for httpd?

Comment: It is in the same subnet as 172.32.35.14

Comment: Try to use `nmap` to check if you can connect to the server's port 80.

Comment: my local machine is windows :( I will need visual c++ env to install nmap, which i cant unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm your server(**172.32.35.14**) where you have install php and mysql right?

What is your local machine ip?

Please run tracert and nslookup command from your local machine:

```
tracert 172.32.35.14

nslookup 172.32.35.14
```

and see where packets drops.

Comment: Here are the outputs:

``C:\Windows\System32>tracert 172.32.35.14  

Tracing route to bp-lamp325-my-apachephp-mp6gbdribkaj [172.32.35.14]  
over a maximum of 30 hops:  

  1   395 ms   382 ms   435 ms  10.200.200.200  
  2   317 ms   383 ms   452 ms  172.23.1.1  
  3   544 ms   406 ms   324 ms  bp-lamp325-my-apachephp-mp6gbdribkaj [172.32.35.14]  

Trace complete.  



C:\Windows\System32>nslookup 172.32.35.14  
Server:  c4p-dns-vip1.in.ibm.com  
Address:  9.0.146.50  

*** c4p-dns-vip1.in.ibm.com can't find 172.32.35.14: Non-existent domain``

Comment: everything seems to fine. could you please check your httpd.conf

`<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>`

it should have `Allow from all`.

Comment: Here is the values in my httpd.conf file ``<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
``

Comment: I changed it to ``Options Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`` and restarted httpd service and tried but still invain

Comment: Please run `curl -I http://172.32.35.14/info.php ` and `curl -I http://localhost/info.php` from your server(172.32.35.14) and check both output `200 Found`

Comment: yes for both its 200 ok ``HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 29 Nov 2015 19:07:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
``

Comment: ohh now i see. its all vpn issue. you need to find default gateway of "172.32.35.15" server and you need to forward port 80 of default gateway router to your server ip(172.32.35.15). ([how to find default gatway](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-find-gateway-ip-address/)

Comment: ok.. let me try that. Can you explain what do you mean by ``forward port 80 of default gateway server to your server ip`` and how to do it? Sorry if its a basic question. Im pretty new to networking

Comment: it is basic when you have router device as default gateway. I also don't know how to port forward from linux system :( . if it is router dlink,cisco,tp-link you can search on google for port forward it very easy.

Comment: ok..let me try. Thanks a ton. You have been very helpful. Will post updates

Comment: **port forward 80 :** As you have connected to vpn whenever you make http request to your server(172.32.35.14) from your local machine it does not go to server(172.32.35.14:80). it goes to default gateway server port 80. As there is no service(http) running on default gateway on port 80 that's why you are not able to load php page from your local machine. once these http request is forwarded to your server port 80 from default gateway port 80 you will be able to load the php page. 
more info :[port forward](http://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for)